# Boundary condition of magnetic field intensity when one of the mediums is a perfect conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

i'm studying boundary conditions of maxwell's equations at the interface of two mediums, for the case of the magnetic field intensity $\boldsymbol{H}$ one can obtain using the ampere-maxwell law that
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{n}_{12} \times (\boldsymbol{H}_2 - \boldsymbol{H}_1) = \boldsymbol{J}_s
\end{equation}
my teacher's notes then go on to say that if medium 2 is a perfect conductor ($\sigma \to \infty$) then $\boldsymbol{H}_2$ = 0, further simplifying the expression, i don't understand how to reach that conclusion.

Comment: Did the teacher mention superconductors?

Comment: no, just perfect conductor i don't know if theres a difference. if its of any help this is in the context of an electrical engineering course on electrogmagnetism, the textbook the course is based on is Fundamentals of Engineering Electromagnetics by David K. Cheng, i did check in the textbook when they cover magnetic field boundary conditions and there was no mention of this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a perfect conductor $\boldsymbol{E}=0$ (free charges rearrange freely so that $\boldsymbol E=0$). Using $$\boldsymbol \nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial \boldsymbol B}{\partial t}$$ we find that $\boldsymbol B$ is constant and so is $\boldsymbol H$ (as long as the susceptibility doesn't evolve with time...).

Now, I suppose your teacher assumes that $\boldsymbol H$ inside the thing that is now a conductor was equal to $0$ when it was made (which is very reasonable), so whatever happens, as long as your medium remains a perfect conductor, the field inside will be $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "when it was made"? Are you talking about a phase transition?

Comment: I just wanted to emphasis the fact that saying: "this medium is a perfect conductor" is not enough to determine the magnetic field. You need to know the """initial conditions""". To do this, we must infer the value of the magnetic field when it was still able to vary. So, right for example, we can imagine that before a hypothetic insulator->perfect conductor phase transition, the medium was an insulator with a given magnetic field inside (for any reason) and when it became a perfect conductor, the medium "kept" the magnetic field present inside just before the transition.

Comment: Here, I assume, that the phase transition doesn't have anything to do with the magnetic field, just that it happens without interfering with the magnetic field in any way...

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that if there was a finite field before such transition it would become "trapped" inside the "perfect conductor" after the transition happens? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I was trying to say. As long as the phase transition doesn't mess with the value of $\boldsymbol B$, I think that it's what happens.